# Как переделывать material design компоненты (MaterialTimePicker)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, material-design

Всем, добрый день!
Уже 2 дня пытаюсь переделать MaterialTimePicker для своего приложения. Хочу добавить секунды, но сохранить всю логику и дизайн от Material Design. Я скачал архив с репозитория, нашёл нужные мне классы и стал формировать свой android lib в отдельном проекте. C Java классами - всё просто, быстро всё сделал, но вот ресурсы, особенно стили и цвета - это жесть: один стиль ссылается на другой и так по несколько итераций. Я так понял, что вытащить какой-то отлельный компонент из репозитория Material Design и переделать под себя в отдельную библиотеку - не реально из-за нескончаемого числа зависимостей.
Также я пробовал переделать нужные мне классы оставив остальные компоненты Material Design и подключить всю библиотеку как aar к своему приложение. Но сразу возникает ошибка Duplicate classes, так как я в приложении подключаю ещё внешнюю библиотеку Material Design, и классы дублируются. Отказаться от внешней Material Design библиотеки я не могу, так как скаченная мной в aar архив - это не полная версия. Переименовывать десятки классов - тоже не вариант. Exclude в dependency тоже не работаеют для aar, чтобы решить проблему duplicate classes.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, сталкивался ли кто-то с подобной задачей? В интернете информациюю по теме, к сожалению, я не нашёл. Может быть я вообще не тем путём пошёл?
Но ведь Material Design - это open source, то есть должен быть какой-то простой вариант переделывать его компоненты?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Вам не нужно скачивать исходный код всей библиотеки.**

Достаточно будет написать свою реализацию нужного виджета, опираясь на уже существующий код.

Comment: Можете подсказать как в случае с MaterialTimePicker? 
От него даже унаследоваться нельзя, чтобы переопределить.
А меня по факту интересует его внутренний класс TimePickerClockPresenter, где я мог бы часы заменить на минуты, а минуты на секунды, чтобы у меня было представление мин:сек, всё с разметкой до 60 на циферблате

private static final String[] HOUR_CLOCK_24_VALUES =
      {"00", "5", "10", "15", "20", "25", "30", "35", "40", "45", "50", "55"};
  private static final  String[] MINUTE_CLOCK_VALUES =
      {"00", "5", "10", "15", "20", "25", "30", "35", "40", "45", "50", "55"};

Comment: Создайте свой MyMaterialTimePicker, и там реализуйте весь код из MaterialTimePicker.

Comment: Это почти тоже самое, что рализовать весь функционал MaterialTimePicker самому с нуля, так как все layouts, темы, цвета и т.д.
Я нашёл интересный подход - отражение (рефлексия). Кое-что уже получилось сделать, но проблема с отражением классов, которые имеют ссылки на XML. Такое впечатление, что рефлексией нельзя создать объект из класса, который ссылается на XML layout в своей библиотеке.
Параллельно начал рассматривать возможность с динамическим изменением классов (byte buddy), то там пока тоже не так всё просто.